# List<int> to a sql "in" query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to take a list and Linq it such that I come out with something suitable for a sql "in". This is what I am using now. Is there a cleaner Linq way to get this `"(333,333,54445,56667)"`

```
List<int> vendorIds;
string snipet = "";
for (int i = 0; i < vendorIds.Count; i++)
{
    snipet += (i > 0) ? "," + vendorIds[i].ToString() : vendorIds[i].ToString();
}
```

Just wondering.

Comment: thanks for the fix-ups in my original question... I get nutty when I get stressed ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET <= 3.5

```
string.Join(",", vendorIds.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

In .NET >= 4

```
string.Join(",", vendorIds)
```

I prefer to write myself a method for that like:

```
string Concat(this IEnumerable<string> items) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 string.Join also takes in `IEnumerable<T>` so you don't need `.ToArray()`

Comment: This seems to be new in .NET >= 4. It was an array parameter (just like every BCL-API was array-based back then).

Comment: Actually you can write it as just: `string.Join(",", vendorIds)`

Comment: good call on the extension recommendation. I'm adding it to my library.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass this using a parameterised query with something like the following:

```
List<int> vendorIds = new List<int> {1,2,3};

string vendors = string.Join(",", vendorIds);

string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Vendors WHERE VendorId IN (SELECT convert(int, value) FROM string_split(@VendorIds, ','))";

SqlParameter[] parameters = {
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@VendorIds", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Value = vendors},
};
```